# Thinking Sphinx - complicated sort on two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using thinking sphinx for search. Now I need to order my search results by two fields.
The complicated part starts with this:

"if date_approved is not null use it, else use created_at date for sorting the results in descending order"

I implement this without thinking sphinx as :

```
@model_values=Model.find(:all, 
                         :conditions => {:name => :johndoe}, 
                         :select => "*,if(date_approved,date_approved,created_at) as my_date", 
                         :order => 'my_date DESC')
```

But when I come to thinking_sphinx, I am stumped.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It may be worth considering adding a new column, something like `last_update`, which is updated automatically with either the `created_at` date or `date_approved` whenever the record is updated. Then you could just sort by `last_update` in Sphinx.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping I could do this one without adding a database column.  I guess that would be the last resort.

Answer (score 1):

On the SQL side, you're probably looking for ROR to produce

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(date_approved, created_at) DESC
```

COALESCE() returns the first argument that's not NULL.